# Android application uploaded using eclipse seems to still be taking up space even though I deleted it

Tags: android

I recently had to build an app which was pretty big (just under 180mb) mostly of stuff in the assets folder.

At one point I was running the application from eclipse and I got a strange error. I wish I recorded it but as far as I remember it was something along the lines of

> Failed to launch application (null)

I was about to try install again when I realized the app had appeared on my phone. I ran it and everything was fine. Then I uninstalled it using adb uninstall.

I tried installing another app and it said I didn't have enough space. The available internal storage on my phone was around 250mb. Now it's 70mb. It looks like the previous application I ran is stuck somewhere in my phones internal storage even after I uninstalled. I had even set

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

The extra content doesn't seem to be accounted for anywhere. The application manager says my largest application is 12mb. Can't find anything strange in the DDMS file explorer.

Has anyone come across this kind of thing before? Is there some way of clearing out the internal storage? If I root my phone and go in to delete the file myself does anybody know where the file might be?

EDIT:

I did try the solution to 99% of problems - turning the phone off and on again.

Comment: Turn your phone on an off lolz

Comment: I did try that :( should have mentioned that I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in the event that this ever happens to another person, taking the battery out removed the unwanted data. I guess I should have thought of that sooner. So Blundells comment was mostly correct but didn't take in to account my pseudo-debility.